# Cross-validation: extracting the model values out per row?

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation

I'm using Leave-One-Out cross-validation for an exercise and was wondering if it was possible to extract the individual test statistics from each validation step.

If my understanding of LOOCV is right, it should be something like this:

[image]

I'm interested in what the prediction is for each of the end results. My approach looks like this (using Iris dataset as an example):

```
attach(iris)

library(caret)

train_iris <- train(
  iris$Petal.Width ~ .
  , method="rf"
  , data=iris
  , trControl = trainControl(method="LOOCV")
)

print(train_iris)
```

The output gives me `0.1784474  0.9448437` for the RMSE and the Rsquared respectively. If my understanding is right, these are the aggregated values across the cross-validations. Is there any way to extract what the RMSE and Rsquared is for each cv iteration instead of the summarized training set?

Comment: Don't use `caret`, but look at `trainControl` and its `savePredictions` parameter. Try `savePredictions="final"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on aichao's response, if I use `savePredictions="final"`, then `iris_train$pred` gives me what I'm looking for:

```
> head(train_iris$pred)
  mtry      pred obs rowIndex
1    2 0.2744045 0.3       20
2    2 0.4143063 0.3       19
3    2 0.3563173 0.2       21
4    2 0.2429914 0.4       17
5    2 0.2035579 0.2        4
```